# .net Internationalization Google maps strange rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, internationalization

I wanted a place to document the issue I had to hopefully help someone in the future.

Main Story is this is the first time we have implemented translations of a site using resx files and a page with google maps is not displaying correctly. We are using `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` to detect and then set the culture of the currently executing thread and a cookie to help identify. The site is redirected to a subdomain like `fr.mydomain.com`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hidden">
    <div id="location1">@location.Location1</div>
    <div id="location2">@location.Location2</div>
    <div id="lat">@location.Lat</div>
    <div id="lon">@location.Lon</div>
    <div id="zoom">@location.Zoom</div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

- location1 and location 2 are address strings
- lat and lon are doubles
- zoom is an int

**javascript**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key=<key>"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    function initializeMap() {
        var styles = [];
        var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
            { name: "Styled Map" });

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").textContent, document.getElementById("lon").textContent),
            zoom: Number(document.getElementById("zoom").textContent),
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
            }
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
            map.setCenter(
                {
                    lat: Number(document.getElementById("lat").textContent),
                    lng: Number(document.getElementById("lon").textContent)
                });
        });
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        directionsService.route({
            origin: document.getElementById("location1").textContent,
            destination: document.getElementById("location2").textContent,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                alert('Directions failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });


        //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
        map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initializeMap);
});
```

This works beautifully for english
[image: working map in english]

As soon as you try the French version things get really strange, but no javascript error. In fact the map dragging, marker placement, etc... are really out of whack.
[image: not working in French]

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling and chasing false leads it came down to a number formatting issue.

Because .net had the thread culture set, the double lat/lon values were displaying with decimal separators of `,` instead of `.` as is normal for French apparently. This is expected behavior for .net, but Google's api either doesn't know what to do with this or interpreted it in an unforeseen way.

I still don't know how to explain the output and why no errors were raised in the javascript console at runtime, but the following culture specification resolved the issue.

**from**

```
<div id="lat">@location.Lat</div>
<div id="lon">@location.Lon</div>
```

**to**

```
<div id="lat">@location.Lat.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))</div>
<div id="lon">@location.Lon.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))</div>
```